# Find the biggest value & return master key

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

`Hi,

For example I've such array:

```
array:3 [
    1 => array:1 [
      "Home" => array:3 [
        "Weight (kg)" => 4.0
        "Length (cm)" => null
        "Width (cm)" => null
      ]
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
      "Home" => array:3 [
        "Weight (kg)" => 3.0
        "Length (cm)" => 3.0
        "Width (cm)" => null
      ]
    ]
    3 => array:1 [
      "Home" => array:3 [
        "Weight (kg)" => 2.0
        "Length (cm)" => 2.0
        "Width (cm)" => null
      ]
    ]
 ]
```

Need to find a way to get biggest value & that's not a problem, I could find it easily, but how to find biggest value & return i.e. key number `1`, cause it has the greatest value from all others.
Must be checked with locations i.e. `Home`, could be an array, need to find in group all maxes & return its parent id to mark as standard elements.
Someone could help with that?

Thanks anyway

I've found max value by method:

```
$max = null;
array_walk_recursive($values, function ($value) use (&$max) {
    if ($max === null || $value > $max) $max = $value;
});
return $max;
```

But can't find a good way to return this element or it's key:

```
1 => array:1 [
      "Home" => array:3 [
        "Weight (kg)" => 4.0
        "Length (cm)" => null
        "Width (cm)" => null
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: And what exactly is the maximum if you have a group of properties? Say you have for example the values [2,2,5] and the values [2,4,4], which one is the maximum? You need to clearly define that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda you can hand over to the "array_walk" functions can accept *two* parameters, key and value. That should be the missing link you are looking for.

I slightly modified your approach that way:

```
<?php
$input = [
  [
    "Home" => [
      "Weight (kg)" => 4.0,
      "Length (cm)" => null,
      "Width (cm)" => null
    ]
  ],
  [
    "Home" => [
      "Weight (kg)" => 3.0,
      "Length (cm)" => 3.0,
      "Width (cm)" => null
    ],
    "Office" => [
      "Weight (kg)" => 3.0,
      "Length (cm)" => 6.0,
      "Width (cm)" => 2.0
    ]
  ],
  [
    "Home" => [
      "Weight (kg)" => 2.0,
      "Length (cm)" => 2.0,
      "Width (cm)" => null
    ]
  ]
];

$max = null;
array_walk($input, function ($entry, $entryKey) use (&$max) {
  array_walk($entry, function($loc, $locKey) use (&$max, $entryKey) {
    $val = max($loc);
    if ($max === null || $val > $max['val']) {
      $max['val'] = $val;
      $max['key'] = $entryKey;
      $max['loc'] = $locKey;
    }
  });
});

printf("Maximum value '%.2f' of location '%s' is in element with key '%d'.", $max['val'], $max['loc'], $max['key']);
```

The output obviously is:

> Maximum value '6.00' of location 'Office' is in element with key '1'.

---

An extended version of above code that finds and reports the maximum value for each of the given dimensions separately:

```
<?php
$input = [
  1 => [ 
    'Home' => [
      'Weight (kg)' => 150.0,
      'Length (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Width (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Height (cm)' => 60.0,
      'Worth (€)' => 555,
    ],
  ],
  2 => [
    'Office' => [
      'Weight (kg)' => 300.0,
      'Length (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Width (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Height (cm)' => 60.0,
      'Worth (€)' => 666,
    ],
  ],
  3 => [
    'Home' => [
      'Weight (kg)' => 500.0,
      'Length (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Width (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Height (cm)' => 100.0,
      'Temperature (°C)' => 55,
    ],
    'Office' => [
      'Weight (kg)' => 1000.0,
      'Length (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Width (cm)' => 80.0,
      'Height (cm)' => 220.0,
    ],
  ],
  5 => [
    'Condo' => [
      'Weight (kg)' => 1250.0,
      'Length (cm)' => 160.0,
      'Width (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Height (cm)' => 220.0,
    ],
  ],
  6 => [
    'Beach' => [
      'Weight (kg)' => 1250.0,
      'Length (cm)' => 260.0,
      'Width (cm)' => 120.0,
      'Height (cm)' => 220.0,
    ],
  ],
];

$max = [];
array_walk($input, function ($entry, $entryKey) use (&$max) {
  array_walk($entry, function($loc, $locKey) use (&$max, $entryKey) {
    array_walk($loc, function($val, $dimKey) use (&$max, $entryKey, $locKey) {
      if (!array_key_exists($dimKey, $max) || $max[$dimKey]['val'] < $val) {
        $max[$dimKey] = [
          'key' => $entryKey,
          'loc' => $locKey,
          'val' => $val,
        ];
      }
    });
  });
});

foreach ($max as $dim => $val) {
  printf(
    "Dimension '%s' has a maximum value '%.2f' with location '%s' is in element with key '%d'.\n", 
    $dim, $val['val'], $val['loc'], $val['key']
  );
}
```

The output is:

> Dimension 'Weight (kg)' has a maximum value '1250.00' with location 'Condo' is in element with key '5'.

> Dimension 'Length (cm)' has a maximum value '260.00' with location 'Beach' is in element with key '6'.

> Dimension 'Width (cm)' has a maximum value '120.00' with location 'Home' is in element with key '1'.

> Dimension 'Height (cm)' has a maximum value '220.00' with location 'Office' is in element with key '3'.

> Dimension 'Worth (€)' has a maximum value '666.00' with location 'Office' is in element with key '2'.

> Dimension 'Temperature (°C)' has a maximum value '55.00' with location 'Home' is in element with key '3'.

Comment: But this must checked for all elements in currrent location, so all type, ie. (Weight, Length & Width) must have the greatest value to find one aggregate with master biggest values, some kind of aggregator of biggest value for current element & location, but location is an array in db so can by dynamic.
null are treated like 0.

Comment: This _does_ check all values in a location, actually.

Comment: I updated the question to enable the algorithm to handle different locations (so not just "Home").

Comment: I already mentioned in the comment to the question that it is unclear what you actually consider "the maximum value" if you have multiple property values to be considered.

Comment: I've sent You some data for example

Comment: @Largo You did? How that?

Comment: Ok, I've removed post with data, but question is, with this code is possible to validate sets againts them? Because now I've greatest value for first, but need to have in all 3 or 4 sets & correct answer will be 'Maximum value '6.00' of location 'Home' is in element with key '0'.' :)
Anyway, thanks for help, I'll try on my own, but can't find type to set pointer for max values per type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251100/discussion-between-largo-and-arkascha).

Comment: I added an extended variant of the code to the answer above. Maybe that helps with the additional questions you now ask. Note however that I have to guess a bit what you are actually trying to do, your descriptions are vague ...

Answer (score 1):

**You could do it this way:**

```
<?php

$array = [
    1 => [
        "Home" => [
            "Weight (kg)" => 4.0,
            "Length (cm)" => null,
            "Width (cm)" => null,
        ],
    ],
    2 => [
        "Home" => [
            "Weight (kg)" => 3.0,
            "Length (cm)" => 3.0,
            "Width (cm)" => null,
        ],
    ],
    3 => [
        "Home" => [
            "Weight (kg)" => 2.0,
            "Length (cm)" => 2.0,
            "Width (cm)" => null,
        ],
    ],
];

$biggestWeight = 0;
$biggestWeightKey = '';

foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
    if ($data['Home']['Weight (kg)'] > $biggestWeight) {
        $biggestWeight = $data['Home']['Weight (kg)'];
        $biggestWeightKey = $key;
    }
}

echo 'Biggest Weight is: ' . $biggestWeight . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Biggest Weight Key is: ' . $biggestWeightKey;
```

**Output:**

```
Biggest Weight is: 4
Biggest Weight Key is: 1
```

And if you want **whole element**:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array[$biggestWeightKey]);
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  ["Home"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Weight (kg)"]=>
    float(4)
    ["Length (cm)"]=>
    NULL
    ["Width (cm)"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```